# Running in an anonymous error of ImportError: No module named kivy.app

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I was editing some changes in my project, and ran into an anonymous error stating ImportError: No module named kivy.app. This error is happening in all my kivy files i don't know why. Here is the code for one of the kivy file. It is all simple but still not runinng.
Code of .py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = Builder.load_file('testing.kv')

class testing(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__=='__main__':
    testing().run()
```

Code for .kv file:

```
#:kivy 2.1.0

Label:
    text:'Hello this is testing...'
```

Error is s follows:

```
, line 1, in <module>
    from kivy.app import App
ImportError: No module named kivy.app
```

If anyone knows what is wrong in my code, or system please tell.

Comment: Make sure `kivy` is properly installed.

Comment: Thank you for your concern, The problem is solved. I have created a virtual environment for the same and now program runs perfectly fine.